# How to compute the determinant of this type of square matrices?

Tags: matrices, determinant

Let $t \in [0,1/6]$, $n$ be a positive integer, then how to compute the determinant of the matrices as

$$A=\left[
\begin{matrix}
1-6t&2t&t&t&0&0&\dots&t&t\\
2t&1-6t&t&t&0&0&\dots&t&t\\
t&t&1-6t&2t&t&t&\dots&0&0\\
t&t&2t&1-6t&t&t&\dots&0&0\\
0&0&t&t&1-6t&2t&\dots&0&0\\
0&0&t&t&2t&1-6t&\dots&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots \\
t&t&0&0&0&0&\dots&1-6t&2t\\
t&t&0&0&0&0&\dots&2t&1-6t
\end{matrix}
\right]_{2n \times 2n}?$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $V=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\pmatrix{1&1\\ -1&1}$. Then
\begin{cases}
V^\ast\pmatrix{1-6t&2t\\ 2t&1-6t}V&=\pmatrix{1-8t&0\\ 0&1-4t},\\
V^\ast\pmatrix{t&t\\ t&t}V&=\pmatrix{0&0\\ 0&2t}.
\end{cases}
Hence $\det(A)=(1-8t)^n\det(C)$, where $C$ is the $n\times n$ [circulant matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix)
$$
\pmatrix{
1-4t&2t&0&\cdots&0&2t\\
2t&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&&0\\
0&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\vdots\\
\vdots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&0\\
0&&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots&2t\\
2t&0&\cdots&0&2t&1-4t}.
$$
Using the determinant formula for circulant matrices, you may obtain the final answer easily.